# Factorizable huge semiprime

Tags: number-theory, factoring, prime-factorization, sieve-theory, semiprimes

I'm trying to understand how the number decimal

The correct decimal number is:

```
163325259729739139586456854939342071588766536976661696628405612100543978684304953042431845499808366612030757037530278155957389217094639917994417350499882225626580260012564702898468467277918937337494297292631474713546289580689715170963879872522418640251986734692138838546500522994170062961577034037699354013013
```

or in hex:

```
0x00e8953849f11e932e9127af35e1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000051f8eb7d0556e09ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffbad55
```

Could be factorized.

This is supposed to be a semiprime and although the sequence of "0"s and "F"s seems to help this problem to be solved, I cannot figure out how can i do it.

Edit 1: I have pasted the wrong number. Now this is the correct one.

Edit 2: This is supposed to be solvable

Comment: Have you searched Factorization Algorithms on the web? There is no known efficient way to do it (otherwise, almost all encrypted systems and infrastructures would be compromised).

Comment: Some attacks exists for keys from some sizes, this software http://sourceforge.net/projects/msieve/ implements some algorithms to solve this in a time fashion. for e.g., if some of those primes are small, it can be compute in a time fashion way

Comment: @paw88789: Haha, I didn't even bother to look at that. Then since it's a semi-prime, the best method would be to divide it by $5$ and get the other factor.

Comment: What is the context of this problem, have you randomly decided to factor this particular number?

Comment: This is a challenge using a weak RSA encryption scheme/implementation for didactic propose, actually I'm not sure this number is a semi-prime since the RSA exponent is 65537

Comment: I tried to use GMP-ECM 6.4.4. and it reported that the number is divisible by 3.

Comment: The number were incorrect, sorry about it

Comment: @Mathphile, please stop adding the "semiprime" tag to every ancienct question that mentions semiprimes. Your edit spree has knocked dozens of newer questions off the front page. Edit three questions a day, maximum, please!

Comment: @GerryMyerson sorry about that. I thought it would help people who are interested in semiprimes to find these questions more easily. I won't be doing any more editing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
163325259729739139586456854939342071588766536976661696628405612100543978684304953042431845499808366612030757037530278155957389217094639917994417350499882225626580260012564702898468467277918937337494297292631474713546289580689715170963879872522418640251986734692138838546500522994170062961577034037699354013013
```

is the product of

```
12779877140635552275193974526927174906313992988726945426212616053383820179306398832891367199026816638983953765799977121840616466620283861630627224899026453
```

and

```
12779877140635552275193974526927174906313992988726945426212616053383820179306398832891367199026816638983953765799977121840616466620283861630627224899027521
```

and according to WolframAlpha both of these factors are prime.

I used [Fermat's factorization method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat's_factorization_method) which works very quickly for this number because the factors differ from $\sqrt{n}$ by only $534$.

The hex representation gave me a clue that this might work, can you see why?

Comment: Thank you! I did not see why that is possible though. I will take another look on Fermat's to try understand it better, do you recommend some reference/source?

Comment: Another question: How can one know by only looking the n that Fermat's is better than elliptic curve factorization (ECM), for instance? And is that a way to generate another semiprime like that (with a big sequence of 0s and 1s) without trying multiplying primes one by one?

Comment: Hint: 10000007*99999998=1000000679999986 in decimal